# How to update time format in python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7

In a CSV file I have values

```
id   description
a1   "[00:01.461]my name is john[00:22.95]I live in NY[00:27.137]Works in[00:28.13]media"
b1   "[00:29.13]Hi[00:32.40]How are you"
c1   "[00:36.401]see you soon[00:41.331]Bye"
```

I want two digit after the period(.), so [00:01.461] will be [00:01.46] so the time format should be [xx:xx.xx]

desired output:

```
id   description
a1   "[00:01.46]my name is john[00:22.95]I live in NY[00:27.13]Works in[00:28.13]media"
b1   "[00:29.13]Hi[00:32.40]How are you"
c1   "[00:36.40]see you soon[00:41.33]Bye"
```

How can I do this in python or database end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.str.replace`

```py
import pandas as pd

d =[['a1',   "[00:01.461]my name is john[00:22.95]I live in NY[00:27.137]Works in[00:28.13]media"],
['b1',   "[00:29.13]Hi[00:32.40]How are you"],
['c1',   "[00:36.401]see you soon[00:41.331]Bye"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['id', 'description'])

df['description'] = df['description'].str.replace(r'(\[\d{2}:\d{2}.(\d{3})\])', lambda x: x.groups()[0][:7] + x.groups()[1][:2] + x.groups()[0][-1])

df
```

```
    id   description
0   a1   [00:01.46]my name is john[00:22.95]I live in NY[00:27.13]Works in[00:28.13]media
1   b1   [00:29.13]Hi[00:32.40]How are you
2   c1   [00:36.40]see you soon[00:41.33]Bye\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you please describe what "lambda x: x.groups()[0][:7] + x.groups()[1][:2] " actually do?

Comment: Yes, so the regular expression will match strings like `[00:01.461]` and `461`, and the lambda just adds `[00:01.` + `46` + `]`